# How to open app from Puffin browser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flash

I wish to play flash content in iPad app so i searched lot then finally i came to know `Puffin` browser will play flash content. 
In my app when user tapping a button the app redirected to puffin browser then it will play the flash content. then again if try to re-open my app from puffin browser i could not re-open it.
I created URL Scheme for my app. after completion of flash video, i tried to open my app by using `myApp://` in puffin browser but it does not re-open my app. if try same way in safari its working.
Please help me

Comment: My first guess is that the external URL opening support is just not implemented in the Puffin browser. So I guess you are just out of luck. Since the Puffin website does supply any information about what is and isn't supported.

Comment: @rckoenes is there anyother browser which supports both flash and external url opening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External URL opening will be supported in the next version. Do you mean you want to manually type "MyApp://SomeUrl" in Puffin and then open MyApp with SomeUrl? Is your app free to download? I'd like to give it a trial.

ps: I work in CloudMosa which sells Puffin.

Comment: To make you answer more complete, you could provide a reference for your source that it will be supported in the next version.

Comment: Thanks for your response..I am asking for External URL opening support.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but there a several documentated URL Schemes on the Puffin Developer Page: https://www.puffinbrowser.com/development/

> Puffin Browser for iOS handles the following URL Schemes.
>
> puffin for http
>
> puffins for https
>
> puffin-x-callback for callbacks back to calling app (iOS after version 3.5)

i.E. use instead of https://www.google.de the Url puffins://www.google.de to open https://www.google.de in the Puffin Browser.

Unfortunately currently workin only for the not longer maintained iOS Versions Puffin and Puffin Pro. The new browser Puffin Lite has afaik no documentated URL Schemes or does it?

Comment: and if you want to direct the user back use the documentated Callback